# Laravel Factory Sequence

Tags: laravel

I am trying to define a factory for a blog post. I would like to have a `Sequence` for the `published` field. I have tried a few different approaches but I have yet to be successful. Here is my current implementation. How could I do this correctly?

```
'published' => $this->sequence([now(), null])
```

I have also tried:

```
'published' => $this->sequence(now(), null)
```

I have additionally tried without the `sequence()` helper:

```
'published' => $this->state(new Sequence([now(), null]))

//and

'published' => new Sequence([now(), null])
```

API Docs: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Sequence.html

Comment: Sequence isn't meant to be used in the definition of the factory. If you try it I'm pretty sure you'll end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: @Rwd that has been my experience thus far but I assume there *must* be a way to accomplish this in a factory definition? If not, that would definitely be desireable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was attempting to do this incorrectly. Instead of creating the `Sequence` in the `Factory`, you should be creating the `Sequence` in the `Seeder` like so:

```
public function run()
{
    BlogPost::factory()
        ->count(6)
        ->sequence(
            ['published' => now()],
            ['published' => null]
        )
        ->create();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `configure()` method of a `Factory`:

```php
public function configure()
{
    return $this->sequence(
        [
            'published' => now()
        ], [
            'published' => null
        ]
    );
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks) mentions `configure()` in the context of a factory callbacks only but you may use any `Factory::newInstance()` caller here:

```php
use App\Models\Post;

public function configure()
{
    return $this->afterMaking(function (Post $post) {
        //
    })->afterCreating(function (Post $post) {
        //
    })->sequence(
       //
    );
}
```

Comment: From your question I thought you want to have a sequence in the factory by default (by calling `BlogPost::factory()`). Hence my answer.

Comment: This is the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

How you can get single record from table randomly in laravel.

```
 $password  = Hash::make('123456');
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->name(),
        'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
        'phone' => $this->faker->unique()->phoneNumber(),
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => $password, // 123456
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        'role_id'=>Role::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        'plan_id'=>Plan::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        'status'=>true,
        'activated_at'=>now(),
        'parent_id'=>null
    ];
}
```